# C# Convert String from Combo Box to Int and pass it

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have declared a variable "string text"

In another fnction I take the value from a ComboBox with a function:

```
comboBox1.Text = gUI.getText();
```

and

```
public string getText()
    {
        return text;

    }
```

and pass the value text as parameter to a program.

How can I change the text in the ComboBox to Integers? There are two states that you can choose from: "Yes" and "No". I want to pass the "Yes" as 1 and the "No" as 0 to the program. How to manage that?

Comment: Not clear but put a parameter in your method, check your parameter, if it is `Yes`, return `1` and if it is `No` return `0`?

Comment: how to save that somewhere? I should save that to the string text?

Comment: You wanna save them to `comboBox1.Text`? If so, you can use them like `comboBox1.Text = (1).ToString()` as a return value.

Comment: No I want to catch the string from the ComboBox and if it is "Yes" then save the value 1 and pass this as parameter to the program. Same with "No"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return an int depending on what item is selected in your ComboBox? Have you tried the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
public int GetText()
{
    return comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

If your ComboBox has the items `No`, `Yes`, and `Maybe`, then if you select `No` result will be `0`, if you select `Yes` result will be `1`, if you select `Maybe` result will be `2`, etc.

Comment: It's not available in that context. It's declared in another .cs - how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

*Well*, not clear but I suspect you want something like this;

```
public int getText(string str)
{
    if(str == "Yes")
      return 1;
    if(str == "No")
      return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

`.Text` property of your `ComboBox` requires `string` type, that's why you need to use string representations of these integers like (or use `.ToString()` method);

```
comboBox1.Text = gUI.getText().ToString();
```

> No I want to catch the string from the ComboBox and if it is "Yes"
>   then save the value 1 and pass this as parameter to the program. Same
>   with "No"

If I understand correctly, you wanna check the text of `comboBox1` like;

```
public int getText()
{
    if(comboBox1.Text == "Yes")
       return 1;
    if(comboBox1.Text == "No")
       return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

But save these value to **where** and pass this as parameter to the **which** program?

If you still wanna return strings, you can use like;

```
public string getText()
{
    if(comboBox1.Text == "Yes")
       return "1";
    if(comboBox1.Text == "No")
       return "0";
    return "-1";
}
```

Comment: does not work. He has convertion problems. My method doesnt take any arguments. I have some other functions and they work but I dont know how to change the string value to int and pass it - How to check the ComboBox value in the getText() method and to which variable I shall save it?

Comment: @uzi42tmp Check the last method I wrote. It doesn't take any parameter. It checks your combobox text and returns `1`, `0` or `-1` as an integers. If you want to return string, you can change your return type from `int` to `string` and use `.ToString()` method in your return values.

Comment: Yes. It can be that the ComboBox Values could change and I will have more than two states (Like "Yes" "No" "Maybe" - so values like 0,1 and 2). What I'm doing now is: getText() takes the string from the Box via comboBox1.Text = gUI.getText() and saves it to the variable "text" which gets returned. That value in "text" I give to a program in my code together with other params like param1 + param2 + param3 + text